# Process Substitution to named pipe conversion

Tags: shell, sh, busybox

I am new to Busybox and I found that process substitution don't work in Busybox. Can anyone help me to emulate below command in Busybox using named pipe.

```
cat <(echo 0 0 1 /config/camConfig.txt 0 3840 2160 8 0 0) - | ~/tools/camera/stream
```

I am developing a camera which runs on Busybox. In order to stream camera for analysis I need to start an application **/tools/camera/stream**, but every time I run this application I need to insert same set of information to the application manually, then it will start stream, after analysis is complete I need to enter number **13** in application to stop camera. So I want to automate this task and I tried above command. Later I found that I cannot do this. I tried the below command but only the first input **0** is passed to application.

```
[ -p ~/config/settings.txt ] || mkfifo ~/config/settings.txt
echo 0 0 1 /config/camConfig.txt 0 3840 2160 8 0 0 > ~/config/settings.txt &
cat <~/config/settings.txt - | ~/tools/camera/stream
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<(...)` is a Bash-ism and Busybox only supports plain sh syntax. An sh-compatible way to do this is to run `echo` and `cat` in within curly braces and pipe the resulting [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) to your tool.

```
{ echo 0 0 1 /config/camConfig.txt 0 3840 2160 8 0 0; cat; } | ~/tools/camera/stream
```

I would do this even in Bash as it's a more direct and thus more efficient expression of what you're trying to do.

---

For what it's worth, I think your solution would work if you removed the `<` redirection from the final line.

```
cat ~/config/settings.txt - | ~/tools/camera/stream
```

Why not use `<`? You're trying to `cat` both a pipe and stdin. If you use `<` that causes `settings.txt` to be redirected to stdin, which conflicts with the `-` and means stdin is no longer connected to the keyboard.

Also, I'd probably stick the pipe in `/run`, which is for [ephemeral runtime files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)—perfect for pipes. (Or, alternatively, `/var/run` or `/tmp`.) And I'd give it a `.fifo` extension to indicate it's not a regular file.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Can you give some links where I can learn about pipes, redirections and fifo's as a beginner.

Comment: I like the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), and the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) over at Greg's Wiki.